# Авторизация Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, postman

Web-приложение на Spring-Boot.
Отправляю из Postman POST-запрос.
Все работало пока не подключил spring-security.
Теперь получаю 401 Unauthorized
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добавил в Postman добавить авторизацию:
на вкладке Authorization выбираю Basic Auth, ввожу логин и пароль.
И все равно получаю 401 Unauthorized.
Что не так?
Может в настройках Spring надо что-то прописать?
Если открываю через браузер то авторизация проходит.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502962/testing-spring-security-with-postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указанными выше способами у меня так и не получилось авторизоваться. Вот решение которое у меня заработало, необходимо создать такой класс:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // Create 2 users for demo
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("{noop}password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
    // Secure the endpoins with HTTP Basic authentication
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                //HTTP Basic authentication
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/books/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/books").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/books/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/books/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/books/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable();
    }
}
```

этот код нашел на этом ресурсе:
[Spring Security Example](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-spring-security-example)

Добавляем этот класс, изменив все запросы и пути на свои. Далее на вкладке Authorization выбираю Basic Auth, ввожу логин и пароль и все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Наконец, мне удалось сделать так, чтобы Postman знал об аутентификации, используя расширение [Chrome Interceptor Postman.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo)

Если расширение включено (щелкнув значок спутника в приложении Postman), вам просто нужно войти в систему, используя форму входа в Интернете, а затем вы можете начать использовать службы, требующие аутентификации в Postman.

Comment: Это можно и без расширения сделать, вручную. Надо просто взять куку из ответа браузера на странице авторизации и прикреплять её к запросам в Postman

Comment: Мне не помог ни первый ни второй способ.